# Correct WFS URL Format (Gaia WFS-T Extender)

Tags: wfs, wfs-t

I am trying to add a GeoServer WFS layer to [Gaia WFS-T Extender](http://www.thecarbonproject.com/Products/gaia_wfst.php) for editing. The available layers are available alright but I am unable to load them into Gaia. Using the same URL I was able to add and edit the layer in both Quantum GIS and UDig. Any hints on where I could be missing it with Gaia? [ why Gaia: It is light-weight and packs functionality I'm looking for]

Comment: could you add the URL - my guess would be versions but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @iant here goes; http://myurl.com/zios/ows?version=1.0.0&typeName=zios:a_districts